# Disabled Ethernet NIC Keeps Enabling Itself

Tags: 11.04, networking, network-manager, interface

My new Ubuntu 11.04 server is having issues with the two Ethernet ports on the motherboard. I only need one port, eth1 so I am trying to disable eth2.

I executed `sudo ifconfig eth2 down` which only worked temporarily as eth2 repopulated in `ifconfig` within a short time.

I then modified /etc/network/interfaces to disable it:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
#auto eth2
#iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

and executed `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and even rebooted the system.

For some reason, after about 10-30 mins, eth2 re-enables itself and interrupts all network traffic on eth1. How can I prevent eth2 from ever enabling itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because network manager is handling your interfaces. You could try disabling the network-manager service, as its primary benefits are its portability (i'm asssuming your server isn't going to be moving often).